# Absolute position of <video> tag

Tags: html, css, video

I got a little trouble with video tag positioning. I need to put video element into image like foreground (picture in attachement). I used different `css` positioning tricks, but in this case nothing works fine. If I change video tag for some `div` element with different content, works good. I'm beginning to suspect tag video could be problem. I didn´t add `css` on purpose, I´m asking for you suggestions. Thanks

[image: example image]

```
<div class="item active">
   <img src="../public/images/xxx.png">
   <div><video height=410px width:470px controls="controls">
          <source src="https:xxxxxx" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: is this something you want done @Frezik  https://jsfiddle.net/c7z6285f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this can help you

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
}
 
video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the image which will solve your issue.
Add `style="width:100%; height:auto;float:left;"` in image tag

```
<div class="item active">
   <img src="../public/images/xxx.png" style="width:100%; height:auto;float:left;">
   <div><video height=410px width:470px controls="controls">
          <source src="https:xxxxxx" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
   </div> 
</div>
```